# Select only letters which are followed by a number

Tags: regex, postgresql

I am trying to select some codes from a PostgreSQl table. 
I only want the codes that have numbers in them e.g

```
GD123 
GD564
```

I don't want to pick any codes like `GDTG GDCNB

Here's my query so far:

```
select regexp_matches(no_, '[a-zA-Z0-9]*$')
from myschema.mytable
```

which of course doesn't work.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: And what about `124566`? Do you mean the entries can't be all digits or all uppercase letters?

Comment: Am sorry I don't understand. What about it?

Comment: Well, try `^(?![A-Za-z]+$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+$`

Comment: good, this does it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern to match a string that has at least 1 letter followed by at least 1 number is  `'[A-Za-z]+[0-9]+'`.

Now, if the valid patterns had to start with two letters, and then have 3 digits after as your examples show, then replace the `+` with `{2}` & `{4}` respectively, and enclose the pattern in `^$`, like this: `'^[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{3}$'`

The regex match operator is `~` which you can use in the where clause:

```
SELECT no_
FROM myschema.mytable
WHERE no_ ~ '[A-Za-z]+[0-9]+'
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
CREATE TABLE tb1
    (s character varying)
;

INSERT INTO tb1
    (s)
VALUES
    ('GD123'),
    ('12345'),
    ('GDFGH')
;

SELECT * FROM tb1 WHERE s ~ '^(?![A-Za-z]+$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+$';
```

Result:

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?![A-Za-z]+$)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are only letters to the end of the string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - 1 or more alphanumeric chars
- `$` - end of string.

If you want to avoid matching `12345`, use

```
'^(?![A-Za-z]+$)(?![0-9]+$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+$'
```

Here, `(?![0-9]+$)` will similarly fail the match if, from the string start, all chars up to the end of the string are digits. Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

smth like:

```
so=# with c(v) as (values('GD123'),('12345'),('GD ERT'))
select v ~ '[A-Z]{1,}[0-9]+', v from c;
 ?column? |   v
----------+--------
 t        | GD123
 f        | 12345
 f        | GD ERT
(3 rows)
```

?..

Answer (score 0):

If the format of the data you want to obtain is a set of characters follewd by a set of digits (i.e., GD123)  you can use the regex:

```
         [a-zA-Z0-9]+[0-9]
```

Answer (score 0):

This captures every digit and letter which is in front of the digits:

```
([A-z]+\d+)
```